# Where does the SSL EV registration number come from?

Tags: ssl-certificate

So I have filed for a SSL EV cert.
I believe I filled it out correctly however I am having doubts about the "Jurisdiction registration number" .

I assumed it was the Corporations EIN (Employment Identification Number, I'm in the US).

Is that right? (I'm hoping I don't have to go register somewhere else... again).

Also someone should probably create the tag ssl-certificate-ev (I don't have the rep for it.)

Comment: You are paying a (presumably large) sum of money for this SSL certificate, yes?  Have you contacted the CA and asked what they want you to put in this particular box? :-)

Comment: Embarrisingly I used godaddy of which I try to avoid calling if I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that's the state registration number for your Corporation in the state your Corporation is registered in, not the EIN (which IIRC, is a Federal number). I remember this because we had some trouble with that number ourselves.

Comment: This is what our SSL vendor wanted.  Your mileage may vary - consult your SSL vendor for specific instructions.

Comment: This is what I've used in the past.